# Why isn't my XSS attack on a dummy website working?

Tags: javascript, html, security, post, xss

In my security course we were given a dummy website to practice xss attack:

```
http://permalink.co/multivac/biteme.php
```

Don't worry, this website is for practice, it only temporarily changes on a particular student's computer, it always resets back to original afterwards.

I want to change the url under "click to download" to point to google when clicked. I am locking in the code below but the link is not changing. I copy paste it all after the ".php";

```
?name=<script>window.onload = function() {var link=document.getElementsByTagName("a");link[0].href="http://www.google.com/";}</script>
```

I never get the url to change, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://permalink.co/multivac/biteme.php?name=<script>window.onload = function() {var link=document.getElementsByTagName("a");link[0].href="http://www.google.com/";}</script>
```

its working correctly, i think you are using google chrome ,chrome prevents xss(see screenshot),
[image]

same experience with Internet explorer(11.0),it also prevent xss
[image]

I tested in firefox(34.0.5), its works

Comment: I'm not too sure how I feel about Firefox after experimenting with this.

Comment: thankyou very much. i was testing on chrome, that why it wasn't working

Comment: @jdphenix: XSS should be up to the website to fix, not the browser. [These filters can be easily bypassed](https://sites.google.com/site/xssvulnerabilities/bypassing-browser-anti-xss-filters), and sometimes the filters themselves can be used to launch attacks (the attacker adds script to the URL that they **don't** want executed, and the browser dutifully blocks it from executing even though the page author intends it to).